# IE removes by &nbsp;

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a

```
<button>Click me<span>&nbsp;</span></button>
```

just for a background image/icon but for some reason IE removes my `&nbsp;`. This works in other browsers.

Comment: Why do you need a non-breaking space for a background image? What makes you think IE is removing it? What version(s) of IE are you talking about?

Comment: cant you give `padding` ?

Comment: just asking, is the content type set to `UTF-8`  in your header ? IE has a poor character encoding detector.

Comment: what exactly do you expect to see when you have a **space** character? My IE (11) does not show `&nbsp;` explicitely in the dev-tools, however it *does* show the resulting space character in the page. Just inspect the element and you will see it has a certain width, indicating the space character is present!

Comment: @KarelG this is not related to the encoding, this is a html entity which is not dependent on that kind of encoding. It would as well work with ISO-8859

Comment: Padding did the trick. Thanks @Era

Comment: And the question is...? Besides, IE does not remove the `&nbsp;`. Try adding `onclick=alert(this.innerHTML)` to the `button` tag and you’ll see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving `padding` from right instead of space.

Comment: down voter.. please add your views/ comments.